# Primefaces validation not working

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am working on a form, where i am using primefaces. When i validate an inputtext, then ajax message is working for only for field and not for the others, please, check my code below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
   xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
   xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
   xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
   <h:head>

   </h:head>
   <h:body> 
   <h2>h:validateLength Example</h2>
   <h:form>
    <p:panel id="panel" header="New User">
   <label for="name" >Name*</label>
      <p:inputText id="name" value="#{userData.name}" 
         label="name" >
         <f:validateLength minimum="7" />
         <p:ajax execute="currentInput" update="msgLastname" event="blur" process="@this"/>

      <p:message for="name" id = "msgLastname" display="icon" style="color:red" />
      </p:inputText>



      <p:inputText id="lastname" value="#{userData.lastname}">
      <f:validateLength minimum="5"/>
      <p:ajax execute="currentInput" update="msg" event="blur" process="@this"/>
        <p:message for="lastname" id="msg" display="icon"/>
      </p:inputText>


      <p:commandButton value="submit" action="result" />
    </p:panel>
   </h:form>   
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which fields do you want to validate?

Comment: Hi - I am trying to validate lastname and name, but ajax is showing msg only for the first field but not for the second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the `<p:message>` tags *outside* of the `<p:inputText>` tags like this:

```
<p:inputText id="name" value="#{userData.name}" label="name" >
    <f:validateLength minimum="7" />
    <p:ajax execute="currentInput" update="msgLastname" event="blur" process="@this"/>
</p:inputText>

<p:message for="name" id="msgLastname" display="icon" style="color:red" />

<p:inputText id="lastname" value="#{userData.lastname}">
    <f:validateLength minimum="5"/>
    <p:ajax execute="currentInput" update="msg" event="blur" process="@this"/>
</p:inputText>

<p:message for="lastname" id="msg" display="icon"/>
```

If you want to show both the text *and* the icon in the validation message, then remove the `display="icon"` parameter, e.g.:

```
<p:message for="name" id="msgLastname" style="color:red" />
```

Comment: Hi Tim can you please tell me, how to add my own error message for client side validation?

Comment: `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("name", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Input error!", "Name must be a minimum of 7 characters"));`